# c++ singleton create child in parent class

Tags: c++, class, singleton

I have problem to create instance of child class in parent one.

Here is definition of singleton (parent class)

```
db.hpp
-------
#ifndef DB_HPP
#define DB_HPP

#include <string>
#include "mysqldb.hpp"

class Db
{
  public:
    static Db& instance()
    {
      // can be added other database implementations
      #ifdef DBMYSQL
        static Db *instance = new MySQLDb();
      #elseif DBORACLE
        //static Db *instance = new OracleDb();
      #endif
      return *instance;
    }

    virtual ~Db() {}
    virtual void Insert(std::string& query) = 0;
  protected:
    Db() {}
};
#endif // DB_HPP
```

and here is the child

```
mysqldb.hpp
-----------
#ifndef MYSQLDB_HPP
#define MYSQLDB_HPP

#include "db.hpp"
#include <mysql.h>

class MySQLDb : public Db
{
  public:
    virtual void Insert(std::string& query);

  private:
    MYSQL *MySQLConnection_;
    MySQLDb();
    ~MySQLDb();
};
#endif // MYSQLDB_HPP
```

I got error expected type-specifier before ‘MySQLDb’

```
g++ -DDBMYSQL  `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs` -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -std=c++11 -c -o mysqldb.o mysqldb.cpp

In file included from mysqldb.hpp:4:0,
             from mysqldb.cpp:1:
db.hpp: In static member function ‘static Db& Db::instance()’:
db.hpp:16:35: error: expected type-specifier before ‘MySQLDb’
     static Db *instance = new MySQLDb();
                               ^
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'mysqldb.o' failed
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You have a circular dependency mysqldb.hpp includes db.hpp, which includes mysqldb.hpp, which includes db.hp .... no other choice than changing your design

Comment: The base class needs to know about the child class to make one. The child class need to make the base class when it's constructed. Except it's a singleton, so you can't. SO the child needs to be a singleton too. And you only make one of those. I could solve this. But I'd rather not: there is no (obvious) reason for the base class to be a singleton. If you just want one, just make one. In general, you can't use a singleton as a base class.

Comment: Do you really need to include a whole file rather than just a declaration in db.hpp?

Comment: Move definition of `static Db& instance()` into cpp (so youmay remove the circular dependency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a circular dependency (which is the reason behind the *current* error you get): `Db` depends on `MySQLDb` which depends on `Db` and so on forever.

This is very easy to solve: Include the `"mysqldb.hpp"` header file *after* you defined the `Db` class. Then move the definition of `Db::instance` outside of the class, but remember to explicitly mark it `inline`. Of have a source file where you implement the `Db::instance` function, and only forward declare the `MySQLDb` class in the `"db.hpp2"` header file, not include the `"mysqldb.hpp"` file.

After doing that you will have another problem, namely that the `MySQLDb` constructor is *private* and the `Db` class can't access it. This can be solved by making `Db` a `friend` of `MySQLDb`.

---

***However*** all of this, the circular dependency and making `Db` a `friend` is a sign of a bad design, IMO.

I might instead do something like having `Db` a pure abstract class, and move the factory-function somewhere else. Maybe using templates.

Singletons and inheritance seldom play well together.

Furthermore, what if you want to have multiple simultaneous connections? Perhaps to different databases of different kinds? Can't use the singleton pattern then.